# CSS In HTML Services Template

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm just getting started with GAS HTML services. I am having a bit of a problem figuring out where to put the CSS (I'm sure it is simple). Below is a simple code example. In it I am simply trying to set the background color. What would be the correct way to set this up and organize it?

```
//Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

//index.html

<style>
body
{
background-color:#e5e6e8;
}
</style>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-    ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>
  <body>  
    <a href = "#" id = "index1" class = "Anchor">I am index1</a>
    <a href = "#" id = "index2" class = "Anchor">I am index2a</a>
<div id="div">1</div>


<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#index1").click(function() {
       $("#div").append("2");
      $("#index1").hide();
    });
});</script>

 </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You have to create two files in your project one is the code.gs and the other one contains the index.html. So on the left in your apps script screen you will see two entries for those files in your project and above you will see two tabs when you are editing those files. Take a look at [this example](http://devtest.lagaroo.com.br/home/dev-test-compare-js-dates) it has some crapy css as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style tag should go inside HTML tag.

```
//index.html

<html>

<style>
body
{
background-color:#e5e6e8;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-    ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>
  <body>  
    <a href = "#" id = "index1" class = "Anchor">I am index1</a>
    <a href = "#" id = "index2" class = "Anchor">I am index2a</a>
<div id="div">1</div>


<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#index1").click(function() {
       $("#div").append("2");
      $("#index1").hide();
    });
});</script>

 </body>  
</html>
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service

Comment: It should probably go after the jQuery UI CSS file as well, as there may be something in there that affects `body`.

Comment: Google `Best Practices` states that you should NOT use `HTML`, `BODY`, or `HEAD` tags.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#dont_use_html_head_or_body_tags

Answer (score 1):

I found this way to do it somewhere (certainly not in google documentation): I have the .gs and the index.html which is pretty standard. Then I separated my css to a style.html within the same project and I put this code in the index.html to refer back to the style sheet: `<?!= include('style'); ?>`.

Then in the .gs I added this:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
  .getContent();
}
```